# Hashing PAN numbers

Tags: pci-dss

According to [this blog](http://www.voltage.com/blog/crypto/hashing-and-the-pci-dss/) PAN number should be hashed using a "secret salt". What they are doing is basically H(Message+salt). The reason you need this "secret salt" is because PAN numbers are limited to certain amount of numbers, which makes bruteforcing dead easy.

I was wondering if a keyed-hash (HMAC) would not be more approriate in this case rather than using a secret salt?

If a keyed HMAC is used, can the same secret be used for all PAN numbers or should it be unique for every single PAN? (so use multiple secrets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hashing with a secret salt" is a misnomer, because that's not hashing, and that's not a salt either.

In cryptography, something which is secret is called a *key*. Hashing uses no key; a sort-of hash which uses a key and requires the key to be verified is called a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). A MAC is not necessarily a "hash with key", and stuffing a key into a hash function does not necessarily results in a good MAC. However, it *is* possible to take a hash function and turn it into a secure MAC, and that's [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

HMAC is a secure MAC: you can use the same key for MACing many elements with no ill effects. If you could not, then the MAC algorithm would be deemed very weak; but HMAC Is considered secure. HMAC also has the very nice property of not requiring an IV, so it is quite hard to get it wrong.

---

Of course a MAC is not necessarily the right tool for the problem at hand. Apparently, people want to turn PAN numbers into "something unreadable". However, the simplest solution (simply don't store the PAN at all) appears not to be popular, so one has to assume that people who "hash" the PAN still want to get something out of it.

There are two main use cases:

- The PAN is hashed so that an ulterior presentation of the same PAN can be *verified* to match the stored value.
- The PAN can be recovered from the stored value, subject to knowledge of some secret.

A MAC would be appropriate for the first use; if the MAC uses an IV (e.g. like CBC-MAC, but unlike HMAC), then the IV must be stored as well, and that one will have extra requirements (typically, to be distinct for each usage instance, or even uniformly random), which gives ample room for critical failures. HMAC is thus highly recommended.

For the second use case, you need encryption (symmetric or asymmetric, depending on the context).

Comment: Good answer but the first sentence is not correct IMO, hash(data) is hashing, hash(data+salt) is also hashing, salt is just more data.
Ofcourse HMAC is the way to go, but hash(data+salt) is still better than just plain hash for PAN numbers because you can generate rainbow tables for all PANs and do reverse lookup. This is impossible with the salted variant, unless you know the salt.